# Issue on Installing Ruby On Rails for specific version on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I had installed Ruby at the version of 2.7.0 and Gem at the version of 3.1.2 when I used the command " gem install rails " it shows an error like this..

Log:
ax@shivvv:~$ sudo gem install rails
[sudo] password for ax:
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
ax@shivvv:~$

Help me to find it..

Comment: I need a Rails at 5.0.7.2 for my work

Comment: Could you please provide the complete relevant part of the log?

Comment: ax@shivvv:~$ sudo gem install rails
[sudo] password for ax: 

ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
 cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Please edit your original question to include the log. You should read the [ask] page as well.

Comment: Previously I had included the Log without ax@shivvv:~$.